# Can NtWriteFile() produce a short write?

Tags: winapi, driver, windows-kernel, nt-native-api

Consider this snippet (handle was opened with `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` flag):

```
IO_STATUS_BLOCK io;
NTSTATUS r = NtWriteFile(h, NULL, NULL, NULL, &io, data, data_len, &pos, NULL);

if NT_SUCCESS(r)
    assert(io.Information == data_len);      // can we succeed with short write?
else
    // is IO_STATUS_BLOCK filled?
    assert(io.Information == 0);             // can we fail and yet write some data?
```

Is it possible for `NtWriteFile()` to succeed and yet write less than requested?

Is it possible for `NtWriteFile()` to fail and yet write some of data? If yes -- how to determine amount of data written?

Comment: for both questions - must not. if of course disk stack not fail during write. device must or write exactly requested size or return error. this is by design. but need understand - that is driver implemented. depend from concrete driver. ms file system drivers (ntfs,fat,refs) of course try implement logic - or write all data or return error and not write any data

Comment: @RbMm Hmm... It looks like the best approach would be to add checks for short write and fail with "bad driver behaviour" error. Does `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` get filled in second case (i.e. in case of `not NT_SUCCESS`)?

Comment: if returned *status* in range `[0, 0x80000000)` *iosb* will be filled by io manager. if returned *status* in range `[0xC0000000, 0xFFFFFFFF)` *iosb* will be not filed. if returned status in rage - `[0x80000000, 0xC0000000)` - no general answer - in absolute most case must be filled. exist several exceptions, but not for read/write file. so *iosb* will be filled is *status* in range `[0, 0xC0000000)`

Comment: I see... Better not to use `NT_SUCCESS()` then. *iosb* is **not** filled if `NT_ERROR(status)` and filled -- otherwise. Thanks a lot, @RbMm.

Comment: yes, exactly by `NT_ERROR(status)` we detect are *iosb* filled. exist several exceptions, but not for read/write file. but anyway for concrete read/write api logic *Information* can be not 0 only in case `0 <= status`